# ¿Cómo puedo convertir una fecha tipo string a date?

Tags: javascript, html5, sql-server

lo que pasa es que tengo este un input de tipo date , lo que quiero hacer insertar esta fecha que me llega así desde la base de datos sql server `"2018-03-31 00:00:00"` y quiero poder ponerla dentro del input.

```js
var date = "2018-03-31 00:00:00";
var fecha =new Date(date);

$("#fecha").val(fecha);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="date" id= "fecha">
```

He probado con el ejmplo de arriba pero no se que podrá ser, o quizá hay otra forma.

Comment: Solucionado. la respuesta esta abajo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¡Hola! He probado tu código, y me da la impresión que el input tipo date recibe un string por valor, no un objeto Date(). Al menos yo lo probé así, y funcionó O_o:

```html
 <input type="date" id="fecha" />
    
    <script>
    document.getElementById("fecha").value = "2018-03-08";
    </script>
```

*Nótese que no debe ir el segmento de hora, sólo la fecha.
**Lo probé con JS básico, pero usando JQuery debiera ser igual...

Comment: muchas gracias, me ha funcionado perfecto.

Comment: Me parece que no es una solución, estás hardcodeando el resultado que va a mostrar y nunca formateas el valor que le viene por DB.

Comment: @Kleith Entiendo que no sea una solución para el título de la pregunta, pero responde al problema de intentar asignar una fecha a un input tipo date. Si el input recibe un string por value, y la fecha desde la BD ya viene en string, no le hallo mucho asunto a darse la vuelta por el objeto DateTime() de JS, sólo para darle el formato O_o... a no ser que necesite usar la fecha como objeto DateTime() para otras operaciones, aparte de asignarla al input date :o

Answer (score 0):

```
function formatDate(date) {
  var meses = [
    "Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo",
    "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio",
    "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre",
    "Noviembre", "Diciembre"
  ];

  var dia = date.getDate();
  var mesIndex = date.getMonth();
  var ano = date.getFullYear();

  // Formato de la fecha, acá puedes generar el formato que quieras
  return dia + ' ' + meses[mesIndex] + ' ' + ano;
}

// Obtengo el valor obtenido de la DB
var fecha = "2018-03-31 00:00:00";

// Muestro el valor formateado en el elemento
$("#fecha").val(formatDate(fecha));
```